# twitter digits api Authorization javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-digits

I am using twitter digits api for my web app javascript. After i get Authentication Completion, I copy paste authentication header and data in Postman (I want to retrive my phone number).

here is my reqest command looks like.

```
**https://api.digits.com/1.1/sdk/account.json**


*oauth_consumer_key="my_key", oauth_nonce="my_nonce", oauth_signature="my_sig", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1481549277", oauth_token="my_tok", oauth_version="1.0"*
```

I am getting this response.

```
{
    "errors": [
{
"code": 44,
"message": "numeric_pin parameter is invalid."
},
{
"code": 44,
"message": "phone_number parameter is invalid."
}
]
}
```

**I am stuck.**

Comment: did you find a solution for this ?
We are stuck with the same issue, with no idea as to what's causing the issue.
I would suggest to add the fabric or google-fabric tag to get an answer.

Comment: can you add solution to this,with sample code???

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem. 
It seems that the request is supposed to be a GET request NOT a POST as OAuth common practice (and the ambiguity in the documentation).